# Combining multiple SQL Queries

Tags: sql, database

I want to make a query to list cats that took longer than average cats to sell?
I have five tables:

Animal, Sale, AnimalOrderItem, AnimalOrder, and SaleAnimal

> Animal table: AnimalID, Name, Category
>   (cat, dog, fish)
>
> SaleAnimal table: SaleID, AnimalID,
>   SalePrice
>
> Sale table: SaleID, date, employeeID,
>   CustomerID
>
> AnimalOrderItem table: OrderID,
>   AnimalID, cost
>
> AnimalOrder: OrderID, OrderDate,
>   ReceivingDate,
>        SupplierID, ShippingCost, EmployeeID

There is other tables I don’t think they have an effect on the query.

I thought of the following ... make a query to calculate days to sell for all ex.:

```
[SaleDate]-[ReceiveDate] AS DaysToSell
Have the INNER JOIN built:
Sale INNER JOIN ((AnimalOrder INNER JOIN (Animal INNER JOIN AnimalOrderItem
ON Animal.AnimalID = AnimalOrderItem.AnimalID) ON AnimalOrder.
OrderID = AnimalOrderItem.OrderID) INNER JOIN SaleAnimal ON Animal.
AnimalID = SaleAnimal.AnimalID) ON Sale.SaleID = SaleAnimal.SaleID
```

Create another query based on the above query

```
SELECT AnimalID, Name, Category, DaysToSell
WHERE Category="Cat" AND DaysToSell>
(SELECT Avg(DaysToSell)
FROM the earlier query
WHERE Category="Cat"
ORDER BY DaysToSell DESC;
```

After running the query it I got error saying

> ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL
>   command

Any suggestions! please

Comment: If you want some help you should try to format your question. Not just copy and paste.

Comment: WOW, this question needs some formatting.

Comment: What flavour of SQL you need spooks. sql server 2005??

Comment: any would help ! I'm working on oracle ..  thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries can be combined with a subquery.  For example,

```
select *
from (
    select * 
    from mytable
) subquery
```

Applying this pattern to your problem seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: you mean making it like Nebakanezer suggestion, can you explain with an example please

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the closed bracket that matches with the select avg

Comment: thanks for that ...
but I really need the help of connecting the two queries together and make it work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've come up with this:

```
    SELECT AnimalID, Name, Category,
           [SaleDate]-[ReceiveDate] AS DaysToSell
    FROM   Sale INNER JOIN ((AnimalOrder INNER JOIN (Animal INNER JOIN AnimalOrderItem ON Animal.AnimalID = AnimalOrderItem.AnimalID) ON AnimalOrder.OrderID = AnimalOrderItem.OrderID)
           INNER JOIN SaleAnimal ON Animal.AnimalID = SaleAnimal.AnimalID) ON Sale.SaleID = SaleAnimal.SaleID
    WHERE  Category = "Cat"
    AND    ([SaleDate]-[ReceiveDate]) > (SELECT AVG([SaleDate]-[ReceiveDate])
                                         FROM   Sale INNER JOIN ((AnimalOrder INNER JOIN (Animal INNER JOIN AnimalOrderItem ON Animal.AnimalID = AnimalOrderItem.AnimalID) ON AnimalOrder.OrderID = AnimalOrderItem.OrderID)
                                         INNER JOIN SaleAnimal ON Animal.AnimalID =SaleAnimal.AnimalID) ON Sale.SaleID = SaleAnimal.SaleID
                                         WHERE Category = "Cat")
    ORDER BY ([SaleDate]-[ReceiveDate]) DESC;
```

Comment: I got missing expression error .. I really appreciate your help guy's